# Python Selenium: Can selenium driver be identified via javascript?

Tags: python, selenium

This is the site that I want to login into: https://nid.naver.com/nidlogin.login

When I tried to log in this site using `selenium` webdriver, it showed CAPTCHA.

But when I type id/pw by myself, keyboard typing, the CAPTCHA didn't show up!

How can selenium driver be detected?

Comment: It cannot be detected, but your human actions can be detected. If there is no human actions(Type one by one instead of flush in, mouse move or something else), then whatever it is, it is at least not human.

Comment: it showing CAPTCHA maybe because you have several login failed

Comment: @Sraw it can indeed be detected

Comment: @CoreyGoldberg Really? Learnt, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your driver. Chromedriver does set specific js variables when it starts the browser. I'm sure other driver vendors have something similar. So, in short, yes. There are different ways it can determine that you are running via webdriver.

Comment: But when I log in by myself manually (without using `python` code) via selenium webdriver, It works. So I think that It's not matter of driver itself... I think there are some human checking scripts on that site... Still can't find it